# How much time do I need to change planes in Zurich?

Tags: transit, layovers, switzerland, zurich

In September I hope to travel from Nice, France to Zurich, Switzerland, changing planes in Zurich, and then continuing on to Boston, Mass all on Swiss Air. The trip will be booked on one ticket.

How much time is need for that connection?

Do I retrieve my bags?

Answer (score 1):

For flights booked on a single ticket:

- Your luggage will be checked through to your final destination in this case
- As long as the airline is willing to sell you that connection, they think you will make it, and they have a strong incentive to make sure that you do, because otherwise they have a duty of care: rebook your as soon as possible, pay for a hotel if you have to stay overnight, pay for meals and drinks based on the duration of the delay, and if it's their fault, pay compensation.

Still, if you don't make the connection (mostly because the first flight is late), you may be stuck overnight or be rerouted via a more complex itinerary, so plan for it. The probability is quite low, but not inexistant.

Also, remember that nobody has any visibility on how the current crisis will evolve in the coming months, and you could still be facing travel bans, cancelled flights, rescheduled flights, and so on.

Comment: For this route the OP will have to pass exit passport control in ZRH, but will not have to clear security again. The connection time SWISS (Swiss Air ceased trading a long time ago) will propose can be assumed to be enough. From concourse A to E would take about 20 minutes, including passport control.